# How to position bitmap in splash screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, splash-screen, android-bitmap

Dears,

I have a square title.png which I show in (also square) TitleFragment on the upper end of the screen in portrait mode (never mind landscape mode). Now I would like to add a splash screen to my app while it is loading. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) and it works fine. My `splash.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/dark"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="top"
            android:src="@drawable/title"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

As you can see I am using the same title.png as in TitleFragment, however, I failed at positioning it at the **same positition** as TitleFragment is showing the image. My `titlefragment.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/title"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

`mainactivity.xml` locates it in the largest possible sqaure at the top of the screen.

My question is: Can I emulate the positioning of the fragment in the splash screen. I would like the `title.png` in the splash screen and the `title.png` in the titleFragment to be congruent. I already played with the relevant line in `splash.xml` (`android:gravity="top"`), but to no avail.

**EDIT:** Here are some screenshots. The first is showing the splash screen:

[image: SplashActivity]

The second is showing the main activity (with dummy text, obviously):

[image: MainActivity]

Comment: Can you attach the images of both screens? How it is appearing in your mobile or emulator?

Answer (score 1):

They do not match because a plain bitmap does not have the same attributes as an `ImageView`. The default scale type of an `ImageView` is `FIT_CENTER`. Unfortunately a bitmap does not have any scaling attributes.

What you should be able to do is, instead of setting the window background in a theme (as *Splash Screens the Right Way* suggests), set the window background in your `SplashActivity`. This way you can adjust the bounds of the background drawable to match the size of the screen:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    LayerDrawable drawable = (LayerDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.splash);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, display.getWidth(), display.getHeight());
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground(drawable);

    startMainActivity();
}
```

If you also set the gravity of the layer holding your title drawable to `top|center_horizontal`, this *should* allow you to resize the title drawable in your `layer-list` to match the width of the screen:

```
<item android:gravity="top|center_horizontal">
    <bitmap android:drawable="@drawable/title"/>
</item>
```

Though, this still may not give you perfect results, especially in landscape. You may still want to mess with the size of your drawable, as well as the scale type of your `ImageView` to get them to match.

This method may also slow down the launch time of your splash screen, which is definitely not desirable. Though, none of the methods I use are resource-intensive, so it *should* be negligible, but I have not tested it.

Comment: Nope. For some reason, all I see is black - until my `MainActivity` is loaded. It is as if there was no splash screen at all. `getWindow().getDecorView()` is not null as I first expected, yet the `SplashActivity` 's background seems to not be shown at all. Good idea anyway.

Comment: @KalaBalik Hm, I would've thought it would at least load. Did you try setting `getWindow().getDecorView().setBackground()` without setting the bounds? I would think the splash screen would display as normal in that case.

Comment: @KalaBalik Or maybe try `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, both suggestions won't work. Same result as above. Could it be that the window is drawn only if the view (group) it contains is drawn?